# Loop through list of ints from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code:

```
public ActionResult DeleteBehandling(int id)
{
    AppointmentDiary _ad = new AppointmentDiary();
    var beh = _db.Behandlingar.Single(k => k.BehandlingarId == id);

    foreach (var item in _ad.BehandlingarId)
    {
        if (_ad.BehandlingarId == id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    _db.Behandlingar.Remove(beh);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("BehandlingarNy");
}
```

`_ad.BehandlingarId` is a column in my database containing `int`. Now, I want to loop through this column to see if I get a match with the input. I get this error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator.

How do I get past this?
Thanks!

Comment: whats the exact data type of `BehandlingarId` ?

Comment: The error message says it all... You're trying to do a foreach on something that is not a collection, but a `int` !

Comment: Ok! is there a way for me to convert the ints in my column to a collection that I can loop through?

Comment: I don't understand... `BehandlingarId` is an integer, a number, one and only one number, there's no point looping on a single item... You should loop on records (lines) , and treat this specific column in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_ad.BehandlingarId is an int column as you say.

So you should not iterate over it.

Instead you should use something like this

```
foreach (var item in _ad)
{
    if (item.BehandlingarId == id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to loop over something that's not a collection (BehandlingarId  is an `int`) - at a guess, i'd suggest you need to change your loop to this:

```
foreach (var item in _ad)
{
    ....
```